# opencv detect position and orientation of bottles

Tags: python, opencv, object, orientation, detection

I'm trying to detect the bottles is attached image with opencv.
mainly position and orientation is what i'm aiming for.

[image]

I tried contour detection and Canny, but this gives me mainly very unclear images and cant see where to distinguish the bottles.

[image]

I think if i can detect following edges i can determine the orientation based on their distance

[image]

Can someone help me out with any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Try template matching. One template for right-side-up and one for up-side-down.

Comment: you should edit your post and provide FULL resolution pictures, not those thumbnails. just train a neural network for this. I doubt template matching will achieve much. all the low level stuff will perform very badly (canny is a newbie trap). you could craft something that specifically reacts to the blue-green caps but that still won't help you see if any of those cylinders are at an odd angle or not (if that can happen). if this is for a pick-and-place robot, assuming two rows of vertically aligned cylinders, and using the caps for up/down orientation, might be good enough.

Comment: oh and you should get rid of the reflections. try a polarizing filter. also use a matte screen for the light, either transmissive or reflective.

Comment: This is the full picture, this is a part cropped from the image we will be using.

Comment: Indeed the reflection is an issue to be solved. i tried template matching ang gave met the best result so far, but still there where many faulty detections, i might start with getting rid of the reflections and try with more templates.